# Segmentation out-of-range fault in destructor

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, destructor

I have a segmentation fault in my destructor but I'm not quite sure why. The code is for a map of key/value pairs which are stored in a Node array and chained to avoid collisions.

```
template<class V>
map<string, V>::~map()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if(hashArray[i] != NULL){
            Node* tmpNode = hashArray[i];
             Node* currentNode = hashArray[i];
            while(currentNode->next != NULL){
                currentNode = currentNode->next;
                delete tmpNode;
                tmpNode = currentNode;
            }
            delete tmpNode;
        }
    }

    delete [] hashArray;
}
```

The debugger points to this line but I'm sure I'm not going out of range.

```
while(currentNode->next != NULL){
```

Any other code can be provided if need be. thank you in advance for your help. :)

Comment: Stop deleting things you don't allocate with new.

Comment: It is all allocated with new though in the constructor?

Comment: hashArray = new Node*[SIZE]; //For the array

Comment: Node* newEntry = new Node; //For each node pair

Comment: Hmm...Hope you have followed the **Rule of Three/Five(if C++11)**.

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar, `Node *tmpNode = hashArray[i]; ... delete tmpNode;`

Comment: I don't think I need a copy constructor etc for this as the implementation only requires one map and the pairs themselves won't be copied, just read.

Comment: Hope etc involves copy assignment operator as well.Besides unless your copy constructor and copy assignment operator are `private` and not defined you wouldn't know if your code tries to use them in a way you don't expect it to.

Comment: @chris `hashArray = new Node*[SIZE];` that dynamically creates the map and then in the destructor I'm deleting the chains and then deleting the null array. There is no deleting of none-allocated memory as far as I can see.

Comment: @Als So  you're saying that I need to implement a copy constructor for the map itself then?

Comment: The debugger points to this line but I'm sure I'm not going out of range. `while(currentNode->next != NULL){`

Comment: Yes or make your copy constructor and copy assignment operator `private` and don't provide them any definitions if you think your code never needs them.

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar, you're deleting `tmpNode`, which wasn't allocated memory with `new`. All it does is point to something else, and then you try to delete previously allocated memory for `tmpNode`, of which there was none.

Comment: I'm deleting the memory in the chain that tmpNode points to, which was previously allocated with new. If that is not how I should do it, then how do you propose I access the array to delete the memory?

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned it up a bit by getting rid of the duplicate `hashArray[i]`s. Also got rid of the duplicate checks for null:

```
template<class V>
map<string, V>::~map()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        Node* currentNode = hashArray[i];
        while(currentNode) {
            Node* next = currentNode->next;
            delete currentNode;
            currentNode = next;
        }
    }

    delete [] hashArray;
}
```